# How to list all available brightness settings with ddcutil

Tags: command-line, brightness, monitor

I know I can see the current and max values with

```
ddcutil getvcp 0x10
VCP code 0x10 (Brightness                    ): current value =    75, max value =   100
```

But is there a way to see all the possible brightness settings `ddcutil setvcp 0x10` can use? Or maybe with another command?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo ddcutil getvcp <feature>` should return both the current value and the maximum value for that feature.

For example:

```
$ sudo ddcutil getvcp 0x10
VCP code 0x10 (Brightness): current value = 75, max value = 100
```

Value minimums are generally 0 with incremental values by 1; i.e., 0, 1, 2, 3... 100.

Comment: Yes though I'm looking for a way to generate a list of all possible settings, without assuming what they are

Comment: Understood.  I don't know of a way to get a list.  I can say that, in my experience, the increments have always been 1.  Never seen anything that did otherwise.  So, in the example, the available values are 0-100 by increments of 1.